# Pie-chart (coord_polar) with frequencies from 0 to 1

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to make a pie-chart of the following data, but struggle with the frequencies. Column `Freq` goes from 0-1 and I want the size of the pie to be displayed as the value in `Freq` from 0-1. So a value of 1 means a full pie.

```
df <- 
structure(list(name = c("bac2", "bac", 
"bac", "bac", "bac", "bac", 
"bac", "bac", "bac", "bac", 
"bac"), primaryTumorLocation = c("Vulva", "Adrenal gland", 
"Anus", "Appendix", "Bile duct", "Bone marrow", "Bone/Soft tissue", 
"Breast", "Bronchus", "Colorectum", "Esophagus"), absolute = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), Freq = c(0.323, 0.0013, 0.0588235294117647, 
0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.0013986013986014, 0, 0.00201612903225806, 0)), row.names = 240:250, class = "data.frame")


ggplot(df, aes(x=1, y=Freq)) +
  coord_polar("y") + theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_grid(name~primaryTumorLocation)
```

I think the problem is that it uses the larges value in my data frame as the max value, and plots with respect to this. I want 1 to be the full pie.

Comment: Try with `+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))`

Comment: better even, use bar charts - you will be able to plot the same thing on much less space. Your target journal and your readers will thank you.